# Remove duplicate characters from 2 strings

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to remove the duplicate characters from an string. I achieved it using BitSet like this

```
private static String removeDup(String s1, String s2) {
    BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(26);
    char[] s1Chars = s1.toCharArray();

    for (char s1Char : s1Chars) {
        bitSet.set(s1Char);
    }

    char[] s2Chars = s2.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char s2Char : s2Chars) {
        if (bitSet.get(s2Char)) {
            //System.out.println("Duplicate " + s2Char);
        } else {
            sb.append(s2Char);
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Although this method works is there some more better and optimal way to do in terms of time and space complexity? Thanks

E.g.

- Input: `"hello", "world"`
- Output: `wrd`

Comment: How much faster do you think this can be done?  You make exactly 1 pass over each string (which you'd need at a minimum), and your bitSet ops should be O(1).

Comment: @ScottHunter in my opinion i thought that it i designed a good solution but thought that may be there can be some trick which i don't know and that's why thought to ask it here

Comment: The easiest improvement in terms of speed would be to ditch the debug printing - console output is actually relatively slow compared to the other things you are doing.

Comment: @AJMansfield Thanks i forgot to remove it before pasting the code, was testing it locally on small data

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what you are doing, you are filtering all characters that appear in `s1` out of `s2`, right?

Answer (score 1):

One issue with your implementation is that it requires a number of bits of storage equal to the highest character value in the string, and only works for BMP characters. Note that the character `a` actually corresponds to a char value of 97. Where you are allocating the `BitSet`, you pass it a size parameter of 26, but this is pointless; a value of 256 may however give you some small performance increase.

If you were to use this on strings containing CJK ideographs, you could potentially use up to 8 kiB of storage with that `BitSet`.

If you instead use a sparse lookup table such as a `Set<Character>`, you can reduce the storage requirements dramatically, but that increases the runtime from O(n) to O(n log n).

Another possibe improvement would be parallelizing the algorithm. Howeverm adding parallelization would only make it faster for very large strings, and could make it significantly slower for smaller strings. In [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), it could be done as:

```
private static String removeDup(String s1, String s2) {
    Set<Integer> points = s1.codePoints().collect(Collectors.toSet());
    return s2.codePoints().parallel().filter(c->!points.contains(c))
        .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint,
            StringBuilder::append).toString();
}
```

This also has the advantage of working for characters outside the BMP.